# CosmosDB Get Scalar Value in C# using CosmosClient

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how to get a scalar value using the `Microsoft.Azure.Comos.CosmosClient`?

I have looked through the web and cannot find any examples.

All I want to do is to be able to execute a query like this

```
SELECT value COUNT(c._id) 
FROM c 
WHERE c._ts > @timestamp
```

There doesn't seem to get any function on either the `CosmosClient` or the `Container` classes to handle the type of query.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

```cs
var container = client.GetContainer("test", "test");
var qry = container.GetItemQueryIterator<int>("SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c");
int count;
while (qry.HasMoreResults)
{
    count = (await qry.ReadNextAsync()).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

It works because you get an json integer array back from the Cosmos REST API. The SDK does a `JsonConvert.Deserialize<int>` (or similar) on it and you know the result of that is the single value you asked for.

There might be a better way, but I haven't seen any scalar method in `v3` either.

Comment: Be careful with assuming the first `ReadNextAsync` has the value. A few more lines, but probably safer to use the iterator and check that you have a value before taking it as the count.

Comment: Hi @NoahStahl thank for your comment, could you explain what else might come back on the READNEXTASYNCs?  Would they be empty, or could the count be split across multiple results? Does setting RequestQueryOptions.MaxItemCount = 1 ensure that count is in the first result? Thank you.

Comment: @jondow I edited the answer a while back as the feedback was valid. It could be possible that multiple requests are made to Cosmos before a scalar is returned. For the example that's unlikely as it can use the index to determine the number of documents, but for other queries/scalars you might need it (e.g. the `SUM` of a property).

Comment: @404 understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = await _CosmosClient.GetCosmosContainer(CollectionName).
                          GetItemLinqQueryable<int>
                          ().CountAsync();

return count;
```

That is what I do to return the count. However, I am still wondering if there is any looping going on behind the scene. I wish I just had a method in which I could return the count.

Can anyone explain what is difference between the solution that I have and the following in the other answer?

```
count = (await qry.ReadNextAsync()).SingleOrDefault();
```